# Import Target from another project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, widget, targets

Hello awesome community!

I am currently having two separate Projetcs. A regular app and another one which has several targets (iOS 8 widgets)

Is there any way to import the widget targets to the other Xcode project, without having to code them again?

Thanks in advance!